# Succulent withering/rotting at the base

Tags: identification, diagnosis, indoors

[image]

This succulent seems fine at the extremities, but it started to wither from the base up...

Can anyone identify it so I can find how to grow it properly?

I put a few drops of water everyday on it, not too much.

Edit: a few more pictures of the plant and the rot.

[image: rot at the center of the image. Notice that the plant thinnes and gets brownish at the base.]

[image: full image of the plant. The obe rotting is the foremost one, very slender.]

I hope those pictures are Ok... I'm having trouble with lighting...

Comment: Welcome to the site! For identification: could we get a picture of the entire plant and possibly some close-ups? And for the withering: Close-ups, please...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to the withering (pictures please) but I can tell you that succulents generally prefer one good watering and then a few weeks without any more. Let the soil get well dry and then water the plant heavily. I assume it's in proper fast draining succulent/cactus potting mix?

Comment: "everyday" is often too much for succulents. Many prefer a little each week, or a little each *month*. Give them too much, and the roots rot. Watch out for high sphagnum potting soil too. These are arid region plants, not something you'd find growing in a pine forest near a peat bog in northern Wisconsin.

Comment: I will take more pictures of the entire plant and the rot when I get home. But regarding watering, even a few drops everyday are too much? As to the soil, I believe it is common soil, not too sandy... I bought the vase as is. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like root rot caused by a combination of low light and watering practice. This also looks like a grower's special where they combine plants with different requirements and leave the rest to you.

- The stems that are dark at the base are dead and should be clipped at the base and removed
- move the planting to the highest light are that you have. An unobstructed south window would do well. The plants appear etiolated or stretched out due to lack of light
- check and ensure that there are drainage holes at the bottom.  If not, this is your problem as Wayfaring Stranger has pointed out: succulents like to dry out and then watered thoroughly
- watering should be more like every two weeks with one cup of water but you need to adjust this based on the dryness of the soil
- small succulents are readily available at florist's.  Add a new one if your planting gets too thin.
- don't be afraid to cut it back if the growth gets floppy by cutting it back so there are one or two nodes on the stem, no more
- you can propagate most succulents by letting them dry for a few days on the windowsill and then rooting them in damp sand

Comment: Indeed, I keep them indoors, so they don't get much direct sunlight. I will try to propagate the rotten one with its cuttings... Does the cuttings need direct sunlight as well? And do you mean to "behead" the etiolated plants?

Comment: Thanks for your tips! The last point is: which succulent is this (species)?

Comment: Good material for a new question with more photos!